# How to identify while getting incoming call in iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, phone-call

I am editing some thing in an iPhone editor application. That time, I am getting a call. How can I identify an incoming call by coding ?

If any one having idea about this, just share with us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at following URL
Could be helpful for you 
[Core Telephony](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CoreTelephonyFrameworkReference/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009603)

Answer (score 1):

You can't. This is actually a FAQ already :-) All you can do is implement the `applicationWillResignActive` method in your application delegate (or listen to the corresponding notification). However, you also get this event when some alerts are shown or when the screen gets locked and you can't distinguish why you are getting the event.

Comment: Do you have any example to listen the notification (while getting the incoming call) ?

Comment: In your app delegate class, implement the `applicationWillResignActive:` method. Or register as observer of the `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` notification at the `NSNotificationCenter`.